# NSView in cocoa refuses to redraw, whatever I try

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nsview

I'm writing an application on mac to measure colors on screen. For that I have a ColorView that fills a bezierpath with a specific color. When measuring it goes well for most of the patches, but at a given moment the redraw staggers and the view does  not get updated anymore. I have been looking for a while now, tried many proposed solutions. None of them are waterproof.

My actual code:

```
    [colorView setColor:[colorsForMeasuring objectAtIndex:index]];
    [colorView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [colorView setNeedsLayout:YES];
    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(mainQueue,^{
        [colorView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
        [colorView setNeedsLayout:YES];
        [colorView updateLayer];
        [colorView displayIfNeeded];
        [colorView display];
    });
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
    [NSApp runModalSession:aSession];
```

The drawcode of my colorView is as follows:

```
- (void)display
{
    CALayer *layer = self.layer;
    [layer setNeedsDisplay];
    [layer displayIfNeeded];
}
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    [self internalDrawWithRect:self.bounds];
}
- (void)internalDrawWithRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSRect bounds = [self bounds];
    [color set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:bounds];
}
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self internalDrawWithRect:rect];
}
```

Any help would be very welcome! My original code was much simpler, but I kept on adding things that might have helped.

Comment: I’d suggest you get rid of all of this kruft and distill it back to your original, simple, example, but share some missing and salient details (e.g. how did you define/synthesize `color` property and ivar; how did you instantiate and use this `colorView`; etc.). We need [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but there’s no way we can reproduce the problem (much let get it to work) on the basis of what’s been provided thus far.

Comment: The AppKit's main loop is what manages redrawing views; it looks like you're trying to start your own run loop(s). Start with a regular Cocoa app using the Xcode template, create a custom NSView, override `-drawRect:`, add an instance a window, and everything should work just fine. Use of custom run loops, modal sessions, etc. are very rare, temperamental, and rather technical. Also, half of this code makes no sense ;)

Answer (score 0):

As I said, the original code was rather straightfoward and simple:
The measuring loop:

```
for ( uint32 index = 0; index < numberOfColors && !stopMeasuring; index++ )
{
    #ifndef NDEBUG
    NSLog( @"Color on screen:%@", [colorsForMeasuring objectAtIndex:index] );
    #endif

    [colorView setColor:[colorsForMeasuring objectAtIndex:index]];
    [colorView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [colorView displayIfNeeded];

    // Measure the displayed color in XYZ values
    CGFloat myRed, myGreen, myBlue, myAlpha;
    [[colorsForMeasuring objectAtIndex:index] getRed:&myRed green:&myGreen blue:&myBlue alpha:&myAlpha];
    float theR = (float) myRed;
    float theG = (float) myGreen;
    float theB = (float) myBlue;
    xyzData = [measDeviceController measureOnceXYZforRed:255.0f*theR Green:255.0f*theG Blue:255.0f*theB];
    if ( [xyzData count] > 0 )
    {
        measuringResults[index*3]           = [[xyzData objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
        measuringResults[(index*3) + 1] = [[xyzData objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
        measuringResults[(index*3) + 2] = [[xyzData objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
        #ifndef NDEBUG
        printf("Measured value X=%f, Y=%f, Z=%f\n", measuringResults[index*3], measuringResults[(index*3) + 1], measuringResults[(index*3) + 2]);
        #endif
    } }
```

The drawing of the MCTD_ColorView which just is inherited from NSView:

```
- (void)setColor:(NSColor *)aColor;
{
    [aColor retain]; 
    [color release]; 
    color = aColor;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    NSRect bounds = [self bounds];
    [color set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:bounds];
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [color release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

When running my measurement loop and after putting breakpoints in "setColor" and "drawRect", debugging always stops in setColor but never in drawRect. Without debugging, the view remains white while I should see all different colors appearing.

As can be seen in my first post, I have tried many things to get it drawing, but they all failed.